# How to print a range of lines between two patterns only if another pattern is included in this range?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I'm working on text files on Linux. I want to be able to print all the lines between two patterns (including the lines where the patterns are found) only if another pattern is found in those lines.

For instance:

```
PatternStart
line1
line2
PatternInside
line3
line4
PatternEnd

PatternStart
line1
line2
line3
PatternEnd
```

I want to only get the first block of lines because it contains the PatternInside.
Right now, all I can do is extract the lines between my boundary patterns with

```
awk '/PatternStart/,/PatternEnd/' file
```

But this will extract the two blocks of lines.

Comment: what if you find `PatternStart` and `PatternInside` but there is no ending `PatternEnd` ... print nothing or print from `PatternStart` to end of file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
awk 'flag{
    buf = buf $0 ORS;
    if (/PatternEnd/ && buf ~ /PatternInside/)
       {printf "%s", buf; flag=0; buf=""}
}
/PatternStart/{buf = $0 ORS; flag=1}' file
```

Here, the `/PatternStart/{buf = $0; flag=1}'` finds the line that matches the `PatternStart` pattern, starts writing the output value to `buf`, and sets the flag. If the flag is true, subsequent lines are appended to `buf`, and once there is a line where `PatternEnd` matches and the `PatternInside` finds a match in the `buf`, the match is printed, `buf` gets cleared and the flag is reset.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/FHuTEc) that yields

```
PatternStart
line1
line2
PatternInside
line3
line4
PatternEnd
```

Comment: Thanks, this works almost exactly as I wanted. I just need to figure out why the newline is not included in `buf` when `/PatternStart/` is first matched.

Comment: @KarlEmm I forgot to include it, sorry. Updated the solution.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/PatternStart/{:a;N;/PatternEnd/!ba;/PatternInside/p}' file
```

Turn off implicit printing by setting `-n`.

Match `PatternStart`, append subsequent lines until a match of `PatternEnd` then check the collection for the string `PatternInside` and if so print the collection.

An alternative solution using the hold space:

```
sed -n 'H;/PatternStart/h;/PatternEnd/{g;/PatternInside/p}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

if there is an empty line between blocks

```
$ awk -v RS= '/^PatternStart.*PatternInside.*PatternEnd$/' file

PatternStart
line1
line2
PatternInside
line3
line4
PatternEnd
```